# how to include the column name in case statement

Tags: sql, case

I need to include a column name in the where clause of SQL query depending on a variable value.
For Example,
1. If I have a variable,say,**@test** and I assigned the variable with the value 1/0.
2. I have a table ,say, **table1** with 2 column names **col1,col2**.

Now, I am writing a query to fetch some data from the table by including only one column at a time depends on the **@test** variable(declared earlier) i.e. I need to include **col1** in the where clause of the query if the **@test** is 1 and **col2** if **@test** is 0.

Please let me know the solution asap.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @tbl table
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int

)

insert into @tbl select 10, 20

declare @test int

set @test = 1

select *
from @tbl
Where Case When @test = 1 Then Col1 Else Col2 End  = 10
```

If datatype is different

```
select *
from @tbl
Where Case when @test = 1 Then Col1 end = 10
        OR
      Case when @test = 2 Then Col2 end = 'sometext'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Select *
From dbo.MyTable
Where Case When @Test = 1 Then Col1 Else Col2 End  > 100
```

Comment: the two columns are of different data types. Then how to do??

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

```
Select *
From dbo.MyTable
Where Col1 = Case When @Test = 1 Then 10 Else Col1 End and
      Col2 = Case When @Test = 0 Then 'sometext' Else Col2 End
```

This version of the query *may* be [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).